# Reporting system with build-in end user reports designer

Tags: crystal-reports, reporting

Good day everyone! Sorry for my english, it is not my native language.

I have a system with server, desktop clients and web-clients. System writing on .net, winforms, asp.net mvc. The end user needs to view simple reports in web-clients, change reports parameters and download reports in popular formats (doc, xls, pdf). Also they need to create and modify reports in our system. In ideal case - in web-client. If it hard or impossible - in desktop client.

I start to see in Crystal Reports side, but as I understand, Crystal Reports does't have build-in report designer. Or I wrong?

I will be very thankful for educating about CR and for recommendation other reporting system with build-in end user reports designer.

Comment: You have to make a parameter form as per user requirements

Answer (score 3):

You can try our [SharpShooter Reports](http://www.perpetuumsoft.com/SharpShooter-Reports-Enterprise.aspx). It suits all the requirements you've mentioned: WinForms, WPF and ASP.NET MVC components (even WinRT if you ever need it), end user report designer (desktop version), export to XLSX, PDF and others.

Moreover, it has multilanguage support and a good support team including Russian-speaking persons as well ;).

Comment: Does it support XBAP? and can it's viewer be customized?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Clear Reports then you can use the AdHoc reporting in the browser. See the [online demo](https://www.inetsoftware.de/products/clear-reports/ad-hoc-reporting).

Or for professional users the remote designer. See the [online demo](http://reporting.inetsoftware.de/public/jnlp/designer.jnlp).

Clear Reports can also read your existing Crystal Reports templates.

Answer (score 1):

You should try [DBxtra](http://www.dbxtra.com), it's very user friendly, given that you don't need to have knowledge of SQL or programming, given that it's drag and drop; althought if you have such knowledge you can do even more amazing reports.